# get the text of an element in a jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do something like this:

```
console.log($('.container .content').text());
```

But I cannot do something like this:

```
console.log($('.container .content')[0].text());
```

I got a TypeError: `$(...)[0].text is not a function`. Why does this happen? How can I get the text of the first element in the selected jquery array?

#### SNIPPET:

```js
console.log($('.container .content').text());
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
    Contents
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
    Contents
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log($('.container .content').eq(0).text());`

Comment: `$('.container .content')[0]` - returns a dom element reference which does not have `text()` method

Answer (score 3):

`$('.container .content')[0]` returns a DOM object, you can't use jQuery methods like `.text()` on it.

Instead use `console.log($('.container .content').eq(0).text());`

OR

```
console.log($($('.container .content')[0]).text());// wrap jQuery wrapper and then use jQuery method `.text()`
```

OR(use jQuery `.first()`).

```
console.log($('.container .content').first().text());
```

Comment: Or `$('.container:first .content')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You are using index `[0]` to the jquery object which returns javascript object and then calling `.text()` which won't work as this is a jquery method and not javascript method.

Either you can use `:first` if you target to have text of first matched element as shown below

```
console.log($('.container .content:first').text());
```

or user `:eq()` for desired index object

```
console.log($('.container .content:eq(0)').text());
```

Demo:

```js
alert($('.container .content:first').text());
alert($('.container .content').first().text());
alert($('.container .content:eq(0)').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
    Contents1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
    Contents2
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `'.container .content:first'` will select first `.content` child from all `.container` parents right ?

Comment: yes, it will select only first one from all matched element

Answer (score 0):

`console.log($('.container .content').first().text());`

This will target just the first of type